# Trying to convert a Dell T420 Single Drive to Redundant. Looking for validating my steps

Tags: dell, cable, power-supply-unit

I have a Dell T420 and read different ways to upgrade it to redundant PSU's.

**Details**

1. I saw on Dell's website a thread where a user asked how to upgrade to a redundant PSU versus the single 550psu. They received a response that explained the parts to upgrade to redundant PSUs.
2. However, the Power Distribution Board, does not have a power plug for 4 SATA Drives.
3. It does have a backplane power cable, which I cannot plug into the SATA power line, because they are both male adapters

**Questions**

- It seems like I need to remove the current drives, add a backplane, buy new HDD Hotswap drives?
- Then I would need a new cage for them to slide into so they could connect to the backplane?
- I can't get anyone to actually validate how they made this work with just the kits on Ebay (dual psu's, power distribution board, psu backplane)

It doesn't seem like I can simply use a kit, because the kits do not allow me to plug in the current HDD drives.

I would be forever grateful if someone can point me in the right directions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was finally in touch with someone who verified that I still needed:

- get a new drive cage
- get hot swap bays / drives
- get a drive backplane

This was in addition to the dual 1100/750 power supplies, the psu backplane and power distribution board that I had already purchased.

Now I need to pull out the original cage and replace it with the new one.

all which can be gotten on Ebay
-cheers